# Use a Neural Network model created using tf1.x in a most recent architecture based on tf 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, version

I would like to use a neural network model created 6 years ago with Keras 2.1.1 (tensorflow 1.x). How can I use this model with the last version of keras and tensorflow? Is there a way to "retrain" or "update" the model easily?
I also tried to use the h5 model in Google Colab but the code failed because Google Colab is based on Python 3.10 which is not compatible with Keras 2.1.1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> TensorFlow 2.x includes many API changes from TF 1.x and the
> tf.compat.v1 APIs, such as reordering arguments, renaming symbols, and
> changing default values for parameters.

You can use `tf_upgrade_v2` in the following way :

```
tf_upgrade_v2 \
  --intree my_project/ \
  --outtree my_project_v2/ \
  --reportfile report.txt
```

tf_upgrade_v2 is installed automatically for TensorFlow 1.13 and later (including all TF 2.x builds).

> It will accelerate your upgrade process by converting existing
> TensorFlow 1.x Python scripts to TensorFlow 2.x.

For more information, check this standard [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/upgrade).